# Can't get index of DataGridRow during button click event. Sometimes -1.

Tags: c#, datagrid, indexing, sender

I'm having trouble with `DispatcherTimer` taking too much resources. I hope someone can help.

I am displaying a list of items on screen using XAML. Each row of the list has a button that modifies information on that row. The code behind needs to determine what row of the list was clicked on. This is the magic part of the code that is breaking down:

```
int row_index = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(sender as FrameworkElement).GetIndex();
```

Sometimes time row_index is set correctly and other times it returns -1. **Why doesn't it ALWAYS return the correct index?** To further my frustration, I can see the correct index in the DataGridRow structure using the debugger. The correct index is there but `GetIndex()` still sometimes returns -1.

Interface code:

```
<Window x:Class="WhyNoButtonClick.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WhyNoButtonClick" Height="265" Width="306">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,1">
        <StackPanel Height="192" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <DataGrid x:Name="dg_driver_list" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="186">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label x:Name="col_driver_name" Content="{Binding Name}" TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextBlock.LineHeight="5" FontSize="12"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Time remaining">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label x:Name="col_driver_time_remain" Content="{Binding TimeRemain}" TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextBlock.LineHeight="5" FontSize="12"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action button">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button x:Name="btn_driver_hit" PreviewMouseDown="btn_driver_hit_Click" Content="Hit" Height="20" TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextBlock.LineHeight="5" FontSize="12"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="105,192,105,10">
            <Button x:Name="btn_pause_active" Content="Start/Pause" ToolTip="Start/Pause stopwatches for all active drivers" Height="22" Click="btn_start_pause_active_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WhyNoButtonClick
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // ### Modify this to increase or decrease the chances of getting the correct index.
        TimeSpan screen_refresh_delay = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 025);

        DispatcherTimer update_timer_dispatch = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal);
        List<Stopwatch> driver_hit_timer_watches = new List<Stopwatch>();
        List<Participant> driver_list = new List<Participant>();
        SolidColorBrush color_red = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));  // Red
        SolidColorBrush color_black = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0));  // Black

        TimeSpan hit_timer = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
        TimeSpan time_almost_up = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 59);
        TimeSpan time_remaining = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Label driver_name_01 = new Label();
            Label driver_time_remain_01 = new Label();
            driver_name_01.Content = "adam (1)";

            Label driver_name_02 = new Label();
            Label driver_time_remain_02 = new Label();
            driver_name_02.Content = "ben (2)";

            Label driver_name_03 = new Label();
            Label driver_time_remain_03 = new Label();
            driver_name_03.Content = "chad (3)";

            driver_list.Add(new Participant(0, driver_name_01, driver_time_remain_01));
            driver_list.Add(new Participant(1, driver_name_02, driver_time_remain_02));
            driver_list.Add(new Participant(2, driver_name_03, driver_time_remain_03));

            for (Int16 driver_index = 0; driver_index < driver_list.Count; driver_index++)
            {
                driver_hit_timer_watches.Add(new Stopwatch());
                driver_hit_timer_watches[driver_index].Stop();
                driver_hit_timer_watches[driver_index].Reset();
            }

            dg_driver_list.ItemsSource = driver_list;

            update_timer_dispatch.Interval = screen_refresh_delay;
            update_timer_dispatch.Tick += new EventHandler(update_timer_dispatch_tick);
            update_timer_dispatch.Start();
        }

        void update_timer_dispatch_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (Int16 driver_index = 0; driver_index < driver_hit_timer_watches.Count; driver_index++)
            {
                time_remaining = hit_timer - driver_hit_timer_watches[driver_index].Elapsed;

                if (time_remaining.CompareTo(time_almost_up) < 0)
                {
                    driver_list[driver_index].Name.Foreground = color_black;
                    driver_list[driver_index].TimeRemain.Foreground = color_black;
                }

                driver_list[driver_index].TimeRemain.Content = String.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}.{2:0}", time_remaining.Minutes.ToString(), time_remaining.Seconds.ToString(), (time_remaining.Milliseconds / 100).ToString());
            }

            dg_driver_list.Items.Refresh();
        }

        private void btn_driver_hit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int row_index = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(sender as FrameworkElement).GetIndex();
            if (row_index > -1)
            {
                driver_list[row_index].Name.Foreground = color_red;
                driver_list[row_index].TimeRemain.Foreground = color_red;
                if (driver_hit_timer_watches[row_index].IsRunning)
                {
                    driver_hit_timer_watches[row_index].Restart();
                }
                else
                {
                    driver_hit_timer_watches[row_index].Reset();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // I need to know what row to modify but don't have an index!
                // ### Debug - Breakpoint here.
                DataGridRow myrow = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(sender as FrameworkElement);
                int myindex = myrow.GetIndex();
            }
        }

        private void btn_start_pause_active_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (Int16 driver_index = 0; driver_index < driver_hit_timer_watches.Count; driver_index++)
            {
                if (driver_hit_timer_watches[driver_index].IsRunning)
                {
                    driver_hit_timer_watches[driver_index].Stop();
                }
                else
                {
                    driver_hit_timer_watches[driver_index].Start();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Participant
    {
        public Int16 Index { get; set; }
        public Label Name { get; set; }
        public Label TimeRemain { get; set; }

        public Participant(Int16 index, Label name, Label timeRemain)
        {
            this.Index = index;
            this.Name = name;
            this.TimeRemain = timeRemain;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Note: Search the code for "###" (triple pound) to see where I put a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it figured out. I used this instead in btn_driver_hit_Click:

```
DataGridRow dgr_test = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(sender as FrameworkElement);
Participant one_participant = (Participant)dgr_test.Item;
int row_index = one_participant.Index;
if (row_index > -1)
```

Get a participant from the list and use that index instead.